# Python Debugger auto start，how to close it？

Tags: python, server

I am running my program on a python server,and it fully started:

[image]

But a few minute later, Debugger auto starts and my program will auto run again.

[image]

Why? How to close Debugger?

Comment: Please post code as text rather than screenshots

Comment: I have found the reason,I use Flask and set config DEBUG=True. Anyway,thanks for your comment.